# How to find the Loan-to_Value ratio of two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to find the LTV which if you are not familiar with a home value is 45% of the mortgage amount or greater.
I have the query but i cant seem to figure out the greater than or equal to function.

```
SELECT * FROM Consumer_Axciom092013 WHERE  MR_AMT = >(HOME_MKT_VALUE(0.45))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , I hope you are using wrong `GREATER OR EQAULS` to operator

```
SELECT * 
FROM   consumer_axciom092013 
WHERE  mr_amt >= ( Home_mkt_value(0.45) )
```

List of [**Comparison Operator in MySQL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)